# What does the term "founder" in "load and founder structure" mean in sedimentary geology?

Tags: sedimentology, stratigraphy

In the context of sediment deformation, why are some structures called *load and founder* structures? I know what a load is, but what is a founder?

I read it in Sam Boggs, Jr's *Principles of Sedimentology and Stratigraphy* and can't figure out why the author uses that word. He lists several deformation structures as being load and founder structures: convolute bedding & lamination, flame structures, ball & pillow structures, and load casts.

A few ideas for *founder* come to mind:

1. the foundering of a ship filling with water
2. the founding of metal (liquifying & casting it; seems vaguely applicable)
3. *found* as in the root of *foundation* (Perhaps the *load* sediment overlies the *founder*?)

Sorry my research turned up flat. My instructors don't know, and the only hint I've found online is the [*Encyclopedia Britannica*](https://www.britannica.com/science/sedimentary-rock/Sedimentary-structures) using the phrase in the same context, but they too do not mention it again.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at definitions online, at Merriam-Webster online we find this as one of the options:

[3: to become submerged: SINK](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/founder#:%7E:text=3,become%20submerged%20%3A%20SINK)

This would seem to coincide with the usage in a geological context from the [US Geological Bulletin](https://books.google.com/books?id=3y3wAAAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=sediment%20deformation%2C%20%20load%20and%20%22founder%22%20structures&pg=RA2-PA28#v=onepage&q&f=true) article found here:

> Figure 29 Outcrop of facies SL massive sandstone in southwestern part
> of Powder River Basin Teapot Dome area Hammer at base is approximately
> 28 cm 1 ft long Load casts are developed where fine grained sandstone
> overlies a zone of very fine grained massive silty sandstone Load
> casts are believed to form by unequal loading of water saturated
> hydroplastic sediments that ***founder into unstable sediments below***
> Overlying the load casts are foresets of planar crossbeds deformed and
> oversteepened by rapid sediment loading from above.

So it appears ***founder*** in this context indicates ***sinking***.

Without seeing your exact context, possibly a layer which shows some intermixing with the layer above due to some sinking sediments during formation.